# Fashioning higher precision tool from a lower precision tool

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm not sure where to ask this question.

Suppose I have one or more rulers with which I can measure distances with up to 1 mm error. Is there a way I could make another tool of higher precision (e.g. 1/2 mm) using these tools.

Assume I have raw materials and I'm able to cut them precisely, along lines drawn with a pencil, according to the measurements made using the measurement tools above.

I think the answer is obviously no, but I wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: If you have a precise compass then you can measure a distance of $2^n k$ and halve it $n$ times using the standard compass and straight edge construction to get a measurement of $k$ with an error of $2^{-n}$ mm.